# Application with Windows Authentication - How to allow mobile users to use Forms Auth

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis

I have an intranet app that works great on the desktop using Windows auth.  However, now users have started using their iPads and windows auth is not great on iPads (no 'remember me', etc).

So I've been researching how best to handle this.  My current ideas are around having another page that is set up as Forms auth in IIS but then this raises a few problems:

- Users know the url for the app is http://appname.intranet.com/ (which is win auth secured);  How can I redirect mobiles to a new page from here?  I am thinking an Anonymous page here redirects either to Forms secured location or Windows based on client.
- For mobiles; The underlying security model is based on Windows auth.  So how do I turn the Forms auth into a windows auth?  There is no security info in my DB.  So the user will type in username and pass.  I know I can query AD and authenticate, I know I can set the FormsAuthCookie to be signed in.  How do I then set the WinAuthCookie?? Any such thing? I then redirect to the win auth secured app, will this work?

Anyone done this before?  Any experience you are willing to pass on will be greatly appreciated.